# what is up with magento 1.9.2.4 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml code?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, magento-1, dashboard

So here is the deal.  The code inside the graph.phtml file is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/*
?>
<div style="width:587px;margin:20px;position:relative;margin-left:-294px;left:50%">
    <div style="position:absolute;right:1px;top:0px;left: expression(parentNode.offsetWidth - offsetWidth - 1 + 'px');">
        <div style="padding:5px;height:15px;width:15px;background-color:#F4F4F4" id="dashboard_<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>_cal_div"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif') ?>" onclick="toggleCal('<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>')" /></div>
        <div style="padding:5px;display:none;width:200px;" id="dashboard_<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>_range_div" class="switcher">
            <?php echo $this->__('Select Range') ?>:
            <select name="period" id="order_<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>_period" onchange="changePeriod(this)">
                <?php foreach ($this->helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getDatePeriods() as $_value=>$_label): ?>
                    <?php if(in_array($_value, array('custom'))) continue; ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_value ?>" <?php if($this->getRequest()->getParam('period')==$_value): ?> selected<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/dashboard-close.gif') ?>" onclick="toggleCal('<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>')" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if($this->getCount()): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getChartUrl() ?>" />
    <?php else: ?>
    <div align="center" style="width:587px;height:300px;"><?php echo $this->__('No Data Found') ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php */ ?>
<div style="margin:20px;">
    <p class="switcher a-right" style="padding:5px 10px;"><?php echo $this->__('Select Range') ?>:
    <select name="period" id="order_<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>_period" onchange="changeDiagramsPeriod(this);">
        <?php foreach ($this->helper('adminhtml/dashboard_data')->getDatePeriods() as $_value=>$_label): ?>
            <?php if(in_array($_value, array('custom'))) continue; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_value ?>" <?php if($this->getRequest()->getParam('period')==$_value): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_label ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select></p><br/>
    <?php
    $_containerStyle = "width:{$this->getWidth()}px;height:{$this->getHeight()}px; margin:0 auto;";
    ?>
    <?php if($this->getCount()): ?>
    <p style="<?php echo $_containerStyle?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getChartUrl(false) ?>" alt="chart" title="chart" /></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="a-center" style="<?php echo $_containerStyle?>"><?php echo $this->__('No Data Found') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Why is there a commented out code here?

Is there a purpose to it that I should know about?

Shouldn't it just be deleted or erased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other stuff in Magento 1, **this looks like an abandoned/unfinished feature.**

The commented code looks very similar to the uncommented code except there seems to be a JavaScript feature to toggle the graph range selector.

Here's how it looks like when uncommented:

Untoggled

[image]

Toggled

[image]

However, selecting a new range does not work so it is definitely an abandoned/unfinished feature.

Comment: What the fudge Magento?  Okay so that is different I guess.  But which of those is better in your opinion?

Comment: @fja3omega which of what ?

Comment: sorry.  Which would be better the toggled or untoggled version?

Comment: @fja3omega well as I said in the end of my post, selecting a new range does not work so I suggest you keep that code commented